# Many to many relationships in EF5 Code First, how can I specify table name?

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I'm quite new to EF, and I'm not really sure how to do this.

I have a many-to-many relationship, exactly like this:

[image]

When I try to add a resource (Recurso) to a profile (Perfil), I get the following error:

`Invalid object name 'dbo.RecursoPerfils`

Where the hell did `RecursoPerfils` come from?

How can I specify (preferably through attribute annotation) the table name for this relationship?

See the models below:

```
[Table("Perfil")]
public class Perfil
{
    public Perfil()
    {
        this.Usuarios = new List<Usuario>();
        this.Recursos = new List<Recurso>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IdPerfil { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recurso> Recursos { get; set; }
}

[Table("Recurso")]
public class Recurso
{
    public Recurso()
    {
        this.Perfis = new List<Perfil>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IdRecurso { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public string NomeRecurso { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Perfil> Perfis { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use Fluent API to configure the table name of the join table.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Perfil>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Recursos)
            .WithMany(r => r.Perfis)
            .Map(mc =>
            {
                mc.MapLeftKey("IdPerfil");
                mc.MapRightKey("IdRecurso");
                mc.ToTable("PerfilRecurso");
            });
     }
}
```

You can go through this [Fluent API relationship mapping tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) for more info

Comment: Thank you. I assume there is no way to do this without using Fluent API and just attributes?

Comment: @ConradClark Yes. Attributes do not offer the full configuration capabilities.

Comment: With the Map method, you can use a fully fluent syntax, too. Looks nicer in my opinion. 

`.Map( mc => mc.MapLeftKey("IdPerfil").MapRightKey("IdRecurso").ToTable("PerfilRecurso") )`